# Extra data about objects in django templates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have django objects:

```
class Event(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   event_start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank='true')
   ...

class RegistrationDate(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(tblEvents)
    date_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=registration_date_type)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank='true', null='true')
    end_date = models.DateField(blank='true', null='true')
```

An Event can have early, normal, and late registration periods.

I wrote a function that takes in an event and returns one of: None, "Early", "Normal", or "Late"

All that works great.

In my app, I want to display a list of events and where their registration status is. So I did a query as such.

```
Events = tblEvents.objects.all()
```

So I have all of the info about the event, but not the status.

What is the easiest/best way to get the status for each event displayed in the template.

I figure that I can write a template tag, but that seems like more work then should be necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a property to your `Event` class e.g.:

```
class Event:
  # stuff here

  @property
  def status(self):
     # do the same thing here as in your status function
     return status
```

The you can do in your template:

```
{{ event.status }}
```

Comment: So it doesn't matter that the function queries the RegistrationDate table? That was what had stopped me from doing this originally.

Comment: @lovefeithswing: No, it doesn't matter. If you are concerned about performance and the result of the query does not change that often, you can cache the result: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make that function you wrote a class method of Event.  Then you can just call it from the template.  For example...

```
{% if event %}
    event.getStatus
{% endif %}
```

...but I haven't done Django in a little while.